# Issue with first() attribute in Laravel 8

Tags: eloquent, laravel-8

I tried to fetch the first element of my DB. When I wanted to bring it with first(), it showed me lots of data, and I couldn't access the data attributes.
Here is my simple Code .
**Model Code:**

```
$all_value_bulk=BulkEmail::where('status','processing')->where('processing_status',null)->first();
    print_r($all_value_bulk);
```

**Output::**

```
App\Models\BulkEmail Object ( [table:protected] => bulk_email_verification [fillable:protected] => Array ( [0] => file_path [1] => user [2] => file_id [3] => status [4] => record [5] => unverified [6] => file_name ) [connection:protected] => mysql [primaryKey:protected] => id [keyType:protected] => int [incrementing] => 1 [with:protected] => Array ( ) [withCount:protected] => Array ( ) [preventsLazyLoading] => [perPage:protected] => 15 [exists] => 1 [wasRecentlyCreated] => [escapeWhenCastingToString:protected] => [attributes:protected] => Array ( [id] => 67 [file_path] => public/uploads/1654107283-test.csv [user] => 1 [file_id] => 74478 [record] => 6 [unverified] => 6 [created_at] => 2022-06-01 18:14:43 [updated_at] => 2022-06-01 19:16:29 [status] => processing [initial_invalid] => [file_ids] => [valid] => 2 [unknown] => 0 [invalid] => 2 [download_path] => https://client.myemailverifier.com/downloadreport/csv/74478 [download_status] => finished [ready_for_download] => 1 [finished_time] => 1654110989 [duplicate] => 1 [free_domain] => 4 [catch] => 1 [xls_file_path] => https://client.myemailverifier.com/downloadreport/xls/74478 [file_name] => test.csv [accept_all] => 0 [role_based] => 4 [processing_status] => ) [original:protected] => Array ( [id] => 67 [file_path] => public/uploads/1654107283-test.csv [user] => 1 [file_id] => 74478 [record] => 6 [unverified] => 6 [created_at] => 2022-06-01 18:14:43 [updated_at] => 2022-06-01 19:16:29 [status] => processing [initial_invalid] => [file_ids] => [valid] => 2 [unknown] => 0 [invalid] => 2 [download_path] => https://client.myemailverifier.com/downloadreport/csv/74478 [download_status] => finished [ready_for_download] => 1 [finished_time] => 1654110989 [duplicate] => 1 [free_domain] => 4 [catch] => 1 [xls_file_path] => https://client.myemailverifier.com/downloadreport/xls/74478 [file_name] => test.csv [accept_all] => 0 [role_based] => 4 [processing_status] => ) [changes:protected] => Array ( ) [casts:protected] => Array ( ) [classCastCache:protected] => Array ( ) [attributeCastCache:protected] => Array ( ) [dates:protected] => Array ( ) [dateFormat:protected] => [appends:protected] => Array ( ) [dispatchesEvents:protected] => Array ( ) [observables:protected] => Array ( ) [relations:protected] => Array ( ) [touches:protected] => Array ( ) [timestamps] => 1 [hidden:protected] => Array ( ) [visible:protected] => Array ( ) [guarded:protected] => Array ( [0] => * ) )
```

Comment: Result is giving you data.. what's the problem here?

Comment: When I tried to access the data, it showed an error. Can you specify how to get the data of any attribute?

Answer (score 0):

You can use dd() than you show first element

```
$all_value_bulk=BulkEmail::where('status','processing')->where('processing_status',null)->first();
    dd($all_value_bulk);
```

Otherwise you use **var_dump** result Not easily readable, is it? The trick here is to View Source in browser, in case of Chrome/Windows it’s CTRL+U:

Comment: It is not the issue of print all data. When I tried to access the data, it showed an error. Can you specify how to get the data of any attribute?

Comment: $all_value_bulk->id;

Answer (score 0):

It returns array in object
You can try

`$id_val = $all_value_bulk[0]->id`;

This worked for me very well